# How to retrieve XML attribute for custom control

Tags: android, custom-controls

I've created a combo box control with a edittext and spinner. 
I'm trying to let the android:prompt attribute be passed onto the 
spinner, which means I need to catch it in the constructor which 
passes my the AttributeSet and set it on the spinner. 
I can't figure out how to get the value of the prompt. 
I'm trying,

```
int[] ra = { android.R.attr.prompt };
TypedArray ta = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(ra); 
int id = ta.getResourceId(0, 0);
```

I get back 0, which means it didn't find the attribute.
I also did a ta.count() which returned 0. So I'm not getting anything back.

My XML simply defines an android:prompt value.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just wrote an answer explaining the whole process for [using XML with custom UI elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695646/declaring-a-custom-android-ui-element-using-xml/2695649). In your case, there is no need to declare a styleable, as you don't need custom attributes. Using `android.R.attr.prompt` as the int id will work fine. `R.styleable.className_attributeName` will only work if you defined your attributes in the styleable and you retrieved them by passing `R.styleable.className` into `obtainStyledAttributes`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a style in the xml. For ex :
   `<declare-styleable name="ComboBox">
       <attr name="prompt" format="reference"/>
   </declare-styleable>`
2. To get the value in the constructor use :

   `TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ComboBox);`

Use the TypedArray get methods to get the particular attribute.

Comment: This, but you should not forget to define a new xml namespace for your custom settings in the layout xml: xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/package.name". And use a.getString(R.stylable.option_name) to get the option.

Comment: Great thanks!
a.getString(R.styleable.option_name) does not work. I get an index out of bounds exception. I presume the index is supposed to be the index within the array, not a resource id.

Using android:prompt also works, android.R.attr.prompt.
My problem was using the wrong signature on the obtainStyleAttributes method. I thought I had to use a Theme. These signatures work:
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, new int[] { android.R.attr.prompt });
or
    context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, new int[] { android.R.attr.prompt}, 0, 0 );
Then
a.getResourceId(0, 0);