# How to act on attributes for custom XML Views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I have created a view called RoundedImageView, the corners are rounded. I want an attribute called cornerRadius that lets me (from the XML) specify the radius. How in the Java code where I have

```
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView
```

can I actually look for the attribute "cornerRadius" that was specified in the XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a link to an example. [link](http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/05/02/android-tutorial-42-passing-custom-variables-via-xml-resource-files/)

Search for "custom attributes android" for more examples.

Also follow this thread [How to retrieve XML attribute for custom control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460074/how-to-retrieve-xml-attribute-for-custom-control)